# Printing documents from secure online system w/ controlled page breaks?

Tags: browser, printing

We use an online system where you can log in with a username and password and gain access to printable documents. The online system uses CSS rules, so that if you are viewing it on the screen it has certain features that are not included in the printout. Also, it has page break rules so that it can repeat the logo on every page and say Page 2 of 3, etc.

This works great on a laptop, but I want to use Android.

I've seen tablet multiple print solutions.

- Some of them ignore the print styling, which is bad because then the page breaks based on the length of the content instead of the instructions of the online system.
- Some of them use an outside app which separately fetches the content, which doesn't work because like I said it is behind a login, and the cookies are not transferred to the other app. (for good reason)

Is there a print solution for Android that does not suffer these types of problems? Can you outline

- What Android versions would be necessary?
- What types of printers would be needed?

Also, keep in mind this is a mobile solution. I can either physically plug in the printer or connect the printer to the same WiFi hot spot, or Bluetooth, or something else you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Android 4.4 (KitKat) has a built-in printing system. It uses "Cloud Print", which can print to a "Cloud Print ready" printer, or to a normal printer accessible from an Internet-connected PC running Google Chrome. In either case, the target printer doesn't even have to be on the same network, if both the printer and your tablet are connected to Internet. You can also use this system to generate a PDF from the content you're trying to print.

I haven't tried using Chrome to print a web page with CSS rules as you describe, so I can't say for sure that you'll get exactly the results you'd get on desktop, but I'd expect it to work the same way.

Comment: Thanks. I still need to know whether the CSS rules work. I created [a test page](http://jsfiddle.net/qu7pX/show/). I'd appreciate someone testing it. If test 1 and 2 are successful, that answers the CSS question. It doesn't answer the login page question, so I also need to know if it works on a page where login is required.